# Where to extract the app's rendered/rounded corner icon?

Tags: xcode, icons

I want to use my app's icon for press releases, web pages, etc. The image I provided Xcode is a square image, and Xcode adds the gradient and corner rounding. I would like to get the post rendered version. Any idea how to extract that from the Bundle? Or is there a more obvious way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use services such as [appicontemplate.com](http://appicontemplate.com/) that will do the rendering for you. These are PSDs where you put your "flat" icon in, so you'll need Photoshop.

Comment: Maybe the Gimp could read them. I don't know, I haven't used it in ages.